# Jquery read more wont work in mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery

For some reason I am having trouble with the following code. It works fine on desktop, but on mobile it wont work and instead displays the whole text.

Here is the html portion of the code:

```
<span class="more"> test  test  test  test  test</span>
```

Here is the jQuery portion of the code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
var showChar = 10; 
var ellipsestext = "...";
var moretext = "Read More...";
var lesstext = "Show less...";


$('.more').each(function() {
    var content = $(this).html();

    if(content.length > showChar) {

        var c = content.substr(0, showChar);
        var h = content.substr(showChar, content.length - showChar);

        var html = c + '<span class="moreellipses">' + ellipsestext+ '&nbsp;</span><span class="morecontent"><span>' + h + '</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="" class="morelink">' + moretext + '</a></span>';

        $(this).html(html);
    }

});

$(".morelink").click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass("less")) {
        $(this).removeClass("less");
        $(this).html(moretext);
    } else {
        $(this).addClass("less");
        $(this).html(lesstext);
    }
    $(this).parent().prev().toggle();
    $(this).prev().toggle();
    return false;
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Please provide a fiddle link or something because from the code you provided, I have no idea where this `.morelink` element is...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, but I have an idea. Change your `href=""` to `href="#"` or `href="javascript:;"`. The empty href might be assumed as no href present, so then the  tag is just a placeholder, but not a clickable link. Give it a try.